# How can I match groups separated by other groups in regex?

Tags: regex

I am writing a regex to match a list of items that follow a specific complex format, so the regex for that is very long. The items on this list have to be separated by either a comma, which can optionally be padded with either one space on the right or spaces on both sides, so the regex for matching the delimiter is `( , )|(, ?)`. Also, I want the list to be between square brackets.

For example, it should match the following:

- []
- [validItem]
- [validItem,validItem, validItem]

But not the following:

- [validItem,invalidItem]
- [validItemvalidItem]
- [validItem,          validItem   ]

The regex I currently have is: `\[verylongregex(?:(?: , )|(?:, ?)verylongregex)*\]`, but I'd like to simplify this to include the regex pattern that matches the element format only once.

Does regex have a method to match X groups separated by another group?

Comment: Better to share some inputs.

Comment: hat do you want to capture exactly? The whole list? Each element individually?

Comment: Another question, do you want to reject the match if one of the coma does not match your description, or is it just a FYI?

Comment: The comma has to match the description. I already said that I'm trying to match the list in my first sentence: "I am writing a regex to match a list of items".

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer. I don`t know if it is what you are looking for, but here it is nonetheless.

1/ Assuming you want to capture the list in one group:

```
(\[(?:complexRegex(?: , |, ?|\]))+)
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/pW2oZ1/1

2/ Assuming you want all element of the list matched separately, this is a much more complex thing (at least for my knowledge...). Here is a working (complex) solution:

```
(?:\[|(?!\[)\G(?: , |, ?))(complexRegex)(?=(?:(?: , |, ?)complexRegex)*\])
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/iB3jD1/2

I don't have the time to write an explanation right now if it's needed. Ask for it in the comments if you want one, I'll write it later today. Sorry...

Comment: The first regex matches a list even if it ends in a comma, and doesn't match a list containing only one element. Also, my question is if it's possible to avoid using the same long group twice because it's 342 characters long.

Comment: You're right for the comma ended list, but it works when the list contains one element. I'll try to fix that :/

Comment: By the way, what are you doing your regex with you can't store it in a variable?